# Is there a faster way to check an attribute value in all nested objects?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I currently this code working, but its performance is very poor — 1.45 seconds seems a bit too much for a simple recursive if statement that only checks attribute values.

```
def _check_delete_status(self, obj) -> bool:

    obj_name = obj._sa_class_manager.class_.__name__
    self.visited.append(obj_name)
    
    if getattr(obj, 'status', 'deleted').lower() != 'deleted':

        children = [parent for parent in self._get_parents(self._get_table_by_table_name(obj_name)) if parent not in self.visited]

        for child in children:
            if (child_obj := getattr(obj, child, None)) and child not in self.visited:
                if self._check_delete_status(child_obj):
                    return True
    else:
        return True
    return False
```

Although `self._get_parents` seems like a counterintuitive name, in this case it is still very useful to this solution: It returns a list with all possible attribute names that object might have as children. For example, an object named `appointment` will have `['patient', 'schedule']` as response; of which `patient` will have `[]` since it doesn't have any children, and `schedule` will have `['physiotherapist', 'address', 'patient', 'service']` returned.

When those values are then used on `getattr(object, child_name)` it returns the object corresponding to the child.

I tried to think on how to do this iteratively, but couldn't up come with any solutions.

PS: The reason for the `self.visited` list, is that sometimes an object might have the exact same object nested inside, and since they have the same values they can be skipped.

Comment: I think this belongs to [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @enzo Thanks, I created a post there too, but I think it's valid on both, since my code here is just an example of what I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: 1.45 seconds on what input?

Comment: @chepner It's hard to describe the input, but it's an object describing the result from a SQL query (each attribute is one column from the row, of which I'm checking if the 'status' is 'deleted'). Thing is that it also brings the tables related to it as the same kind of object, sometimes with other objects inside.

Comment: @chepner The input object was like (ignoring unnecessary attributes): `{'appointment': {'status': 'active', 'patient': {'status': 'active'}, 'schedule': {'status': 'active', 'physiotherapist': {'status': 'active'}, 'address': {'status': 'active', 'organization': {'status': 'active'}}, 'patient': {'status': 'active'}, 'service': {'status': 'active', 'organization': {'status': 'active'}}}}}`

Answer (score 0):

I should've done this before, but I ran cProfile on my function and discovered that what was making it slow was totally unrelated to it being recursive or anything: SQLAlchemy was performing lazy-loading so it had to send some requests to get all relationships it needed which slowed my function down quite a bit.

After I added `lazy='immediate'` to my `mapper` parameters it ran smoothly under 0.0006 seconds.